# name change will not allow lap top to reboot

Tags: laptop, rename, system-restore, error-logging

I have a Samsung N150 laptop. I renamed the full computer name and username (both are the same), required to restart, when I restarted I get an error "incorrect Disk, remove and try again".
same error when starting safe mode.

I removed all devices but now when I restart the computer it says Windows has shutdown to prevent damage to the computer.

Comment: We'll need more info than that. Please update your question to include more information like the **exact** error messages you see when your computer boots up